# How to match points on rendered images?

Tags: python, rendering

I have several rendered images of object from different views. I take one rendered image. Every point on rendered image (2D coordinates) is matched to point in world (I call point of image as "projection", because it is a projection of point in world on camera plane), so list of points in world are presented on chosen rendered image. My goal is to explore what points from list are presented on other rendered images. I believe this process can be done before getting rendered images.

Something like that (red and yellow points)[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your end goal? Can you provide a detailed walk through, the example in the initial post is too basic to get an idea how it would work. And just to be clear you are talking about Camera objects in Blender, not rendered images or photos from physical cameras?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about Camera objects in Blender. The end goal is to check whether real points that projections are presented on specific rendered image are projected on another image. So I have to get some kind of binary mask with shape of specified rendered image.

Comment: Sorry still not following you. "Real points"? pixels? Are you dealing with this from a 2D rendered point of view or 3D real-time? What is the projection, a pattern, light or purely mathematical?

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation, I try to explain with more details. I have several rendered images of object from different views. I take one rendered image. Every point on rendered image (2D coordinates) is matched to point in world (I call point of image as "projection", because it is a projection of point in world on camera plane), so list of points in world are presented on chosen rendered image. My goal is to explore what points from list are presented on other rendered images. I believe this process can be done before getting rendered images. I hope I didn't make mistakes in terms.

Comment: That make more sense. I suggest you edit your question with clear examples of each workflow step. Editing your question will put in front of more eyeballs and if it is clear enough other will make suggestions.